# "Find all" through command in Sublime plugin?

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I thought it would be:

`window.run_command("find_all", {"pattern": "a"})`

to find all the "a" characters in the current buffer (I mean the same effect as using "find all" from the find panel; end up with a multi-selection of every "a" character in the buffer), but it just does nothing.

(I tested that replacing it with something like:

`window.run_command("move", {"by": "lines", "forward": True})`

*does* work, so I at least got the *context* for the code right.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Sublime Text 2 [API docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) (also the same in [ST3](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html)), `find()` and `find_all()` are methods of [`sublime.View`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.View), so you should call them on a `view`, not on a `window`. Here's a sample plugin to search for and select all occurrences of `python`:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class HighlightPythonCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        count = 0
        for rgn in self.view.find_all('python'):
            self.view.sel().add(rgn)
            count += 1

        sublime.status_message('Added ' + str(count) + ' regions.')
```

After saving it in your `Packages/User` directory, you can run it from the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) using

```py
view.run_command("highlight_python")
```

---

For searching for your `≡` character, try this version:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class HighlightTripleEqualsCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        search = unichr(0x2261) # your character in hex
        self.view.sel().clear() # clear any existing selections - ideally we'd
                                # save them and reinstate them afterwards...
        count = 0
        for rgn in self.view.find_all(search):
            self.view.sel().add(rgn)
            count += 1

        sublime.status_message('Added ' + str(count) + ' regions.')
```

Comment: Need to find character "≡". Got "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file ./HighlightPython.py on line 9, but no encoding declared". Added `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file ./HighlightPython.py on line 9, but no encoding declared`, and now it just silently does nothing...

Comment: try `for rgn in self.view.find_all(u'≡'):` to make it a Unicode string. I'm used to programming in Python 3, where all strings are Unicode, but ST2 uses Python 2.6 behind the scenes. Hopefully this will work.

Comment: Hm, played around a bunch and found that just *having the character in the .py file stops it from working*. Even if it's just in a comment. Gaaaarhghghgh. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Owen_R have you tried matching for `\xe2` as an escape sequence? Also, you might want to try a bytestring, and/or play around with `str.encode()` and `str.decode()`. Don't give up yet!

Comment: Heh, kk. Fixed it, edited the code in your answer to exactly what I ended up using. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Owen_R your edits got rejected for changing the answer too much, but I added them back in as a new plugin below. Cheers!

Comment: Cool cool. Actually for my specific purposes *here* it's best *not* to reinstate the selection, but how *would* you do tha?

Comment: @Owen_R - `self.view.sel()` returns a list of 2-item tuples. Save that in a variable someplace, then once you're done with your other business just call `self.view.sel().add(varname)` and you're all set.